# Button can't work in IE

Tags: html, internet-explorer, button, jsf-2, primefaces

In my application, I have the following combination of `<h:outputLink>` and `<p:commandButton>`:

```
<h:outputLink target="_blank" value="theURL">
    <p:commandButton value="Click" type="button" />
</h:outputLink>
```

The above button works normally in Chrome and Firefox. However, when I use IE, nothing happens when I click the button.

I'd be very grateful if you could give me any advice.

Comment: Did you check the generated HTML code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The resulting HTML markup makes syntactically no sense. You end up with an

```html
<a><button></button></a>
```

Whose action should be invoked? The one of the link or the button?

I'd suggest to just use `<p:button>` with a `window.open()`.

```html
<p:button value="Click" onclick="window.open('theURL');return false;" />
```

If using the link was for pure SEO purposes, then I'd suggest to replace the `<p:commandButton>` by its own generated markup as a `<span>` instead of as `<button>`. E.g.

```html
<h:outputLink target="_blank" value="theURL">
    <span class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" type="button">
        <span class="ui-button-text">Click</span>
    </span>
</h:outputLink>
```

Comment: I have a small question. I did specify the button type to be `type="button"`. Doesn't this mean that this button is simply a clickable button without any action?

Comment: The `<button>` will in MSIE submit the `value` or the body content, if any, to the parent `<form>`.